# Difference between local multivariate optimization and stochastic gradient descent?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent, neural-networks

Sorry if this sounds like a basic question but I don't understand what is the difference between `local multivariate numerical optimization (minimization)` and `stochastic gradient descent` used in neural networks.

- Examples of multivariate numerical optimizers: Nelder-Mead algorithm, Powell algorithm, Conjugate Gradient algorithm, BFGS algorithm , et al
- Examples of stochastic gradient descent: ISGD, Momentum, Averaged stochastic gradient descent, AdaGrad, Adam, et al

What is the difference between these two classes of mathematical algorithms, when to use each and for what types or topology of functions? To my understanding both classes are used in NN systems, when to use which?

Comment: The numerical optimizers you mentioned are deterministic and will always converge to a local minimum if found. SGD methods are stochastic in the sense that they may jump out of local minima and thus (possibly) end up in a global minimum. Thus if you don't know whether your problem is convex it might be a good idea to use SGD.

Comment: @Mikal so is SGD a global minimum finder, if so then what is the difference between SGD and global optimizers like Differential Evolution, Basinhopper, SHGO,etc..?

Comment: SGD is gradient-based and will typically be faster than Basinhopping. Computing a gradient requires some work but will allow you to use the slope of your function in the minimization procedure.